# How to mount Android device as USB mass storage instead of MTP?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, data-recovery, linux, mount, usb-mass-storage

I accidentally removed my whole file system on my LG G3 Beat (a.k.a mini) D723tr running Android 5.0.2 Lollipop. I tried to recover my files with my Linux Mint (Rosa) PC using PhotoRec program, but PhotoRec can only detect directly connected devices to the system. My phone only makes connections with MTP and PTP. If I can mount my phone to my PC as a UMS (USB mass storage), PhotoRec will detect my device.

Is there any way to mount my phone as UMS?

Comment: [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526)

Comment: Related: [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205559/218526)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to mount your `/data` partition as Mass Storage:

1. Boot to recovery
2. `mount | grep /data`
   (Note down the device file `/dev/block/...`)
3. `umount /data`
4. `find /sys -name lun*`
   (Note down the URL containing `f_mass_storage`)
5. `adb shell`
6. `su`
7. `cd /data/local/tmp`
8. `vim usb_mount.sh`
9. Press "i" key to enter Insert Mode
10. ```
    echo 0 > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable
    echo [Previously noted down device file] > [Previously noted down URL]/file
    echo mass_storage > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/functions
    echo 1 > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable
    ```
11. Press "Escape" key to go back to Command Mode
12. Write `:wq` and press Enter to save and quit
13. `chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/usb_mount.sh`
14. `sh /data/local/tmp/usb_mount.sh`

This should disconnect and reconnect your device as USB Mass Storage.

Comment: I have a question... from where did that script at point 8 pop up?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman That's not an existing script, he's **creating that script** using `vim`, then then at step 9, **enters input mode** and at step 10, **enters the contents** of the script . At step 11, he saves(writes) the file and quits vim. (Check the [vim Documentation](http://www.vim.org/docs.php) if you're not clear.) Well yeah, that would have been comfortable to read if the answerer has included all these with the explanations in the same point.

Comment: @GokulNC Good explanation.. Go ahead and edit my answer..